# Mac Pro with fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14 will not boot

Tags: mac, server.app, mac-pro, unix

I installed Ubuntu Server 14 on my Mac Pro and now after a successful installation, when I tried to reboot it, the computer chimes like a Mac always does, but does not load any further.  Normally I would see a grey screen then code as ubuntu loads and finally I would be prompted with a password.

It does non of that, any idea why this would be, I had Ubuntu 12 running great however quite a few corrupt files caused the upgrade to 14 to fail, and I erased the harddrive back to empty, and did a fresh install of 14.  Everything seemed to go just fine until now.

What can or should I do to try and fix this.

EDIT: I now see the grey screen but then nothing happens after that

Comment: Hold down cmd + v when starting (verbose mode) where does it get hung up?

Comment: I was able to solve it by wiping the drive again, and reinstalling.  Must have not installed correctly

Comment: wana make that a answer so we can move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by wiping the drive again, and reinstalling. Must have not installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have problem, that loading stop. But I could load ubuntu in safe mode.

I solve issue by edit Grub config, as suggested here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro#Fixing_Grub. Actually I did only #3,4,5,6.

```
  # load ubuntu in safe mode or root console
  vim /etc/default/grub
  # change line in file to -> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
  update-grub
  shutdown -r now
```